# I am new to flutter and I am facing this issue (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Here is my code and it shows me that the error is in here somewhere, can anyone help?`

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  User get getUser => _user!;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

`

I tried to fix it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the user is null  `User get getUser => _user!;`. You can get nullable user and while using it, do a null check on ui side.

```dart
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  User? get getUser => _user;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```